# AndroidStudio 15.1 emulator error 'mksdcard.exe' is missing from the SDK tools folder

Tags: android-studio

My android studio 15.1 gives this error when i try to run an emulator and it does not allow me to click on the button AVD manager. please help

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Welcome to Stackoverflow! Can you please elaborate your question having your effort like code or something so that people could get your problem early and help you? Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

I was faceting the same error. When I had been trying to add a new Virtual Device Android Studio was telling me Android Emulator was not installed even though it was installed. If I was keeping trying to add to the virtual device it warned me to check logs.

Looking at my idea.log file I found the following message

```
'mksdcard' is missing from the SDK tools folder.
```

So I tried to reinstall Android Emulator from SDK Manager at Tools -> SDK Manager and it was solved.